# Can I create a login system in Unity without using Photon authentication?

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, photon

I'm having trouble making a login system inside Photon for Unity, I've already tried to do everything, I ran the entire Google and tried everything but I always have some mistake! On my last attempt I got this error on my Unity console:

```
Operation failed: OperationResponse 230: ReturnCode: 32755 (Custom authentication service error: Error). Parameters: {} Server: NameServer
 UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
 NetworkingPeer:OnOperationResponse(OperationResponse) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:1623)
 ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase:DeserializeMessageAndCallback(Byte[])
 ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
 ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
 PhotonHandler:Update() (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonHandler.cs:158)
```

And also this other error:

```
 Custom Authentication failed (either due to user-input or configuration or AuthParameter string format). Calling: OnCustomAuthenticationFailed()
 UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
 NetworkingPeer:OnOperationResponse(OperationResponse) (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs:1660)
 ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase:DeserializeMessageAndCallback(Byte[])
 ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
 ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer:DispatchIncomingCommands()
 PhotonHandler:Update() (at Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PhotonHandler.cs:158)
```

So I got tired of using Photon Auth, and wanted to know if I can create a login system inside Unity itself, not Photon, Photon will only show the names of the players to the other players, and other things normally. Is there a problem with authentication being only on Unity and not on Photon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at WWWForm for unity, you will have to do some server side programming to store the data in a database but should be easy with PHP. You will have to write some C# code to parse the data in unity (as string) before posting the form and sorting the data when you get the object back.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a login system that is *just* in Unity.
This is because logins need to be stored on a server, usually a database. Logins would serve no useful purpose if they were just stored locally because at that point, why would users need to log in?

The next best option would be to create a database, and host it using a service such as Google Cloud or Amazon Web Services. I personally use Microsoft SQL Server, since Entity Framework is a really well supported ORM (object-relational mapper) and works very well within Visual Studio. Also, look into *hashing and salting*. This is how you encrypt your passwords within your database, just in case someone, later on, decides they want to steal logins from the game you worked so hard on. It's better to handle these issues now so the consequences never come up later.

---

Here are some links that I would recommend to get started if you are completely new to databases :

- [Learn SQL in 1 Hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Pzj7Aj25lw)
- [Introduction to Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I was already using a database, but I could not make Photon work, it always gave some kind of error. So I decided to make a login system from Unity, not from Photon Authentication, so I save the user name of the player in Json when he logs in, and only passes the other users the name of the player, and everything else of the multiplayer, normal game.
Could this be possible? Do I depend on Photon Authentication?